# Find elements on webpage with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have `XPath`

```
/html/body/div[@id='page']/div[@id='page-inner']/div[@id='main-box']/div[@class='in1']/div[@id='content-and-context']/div[@id='content']/div[@class='under-bar']/table[@class='flights']/tbody/tr[@id='flight-932539']/td[2]:
```

But flight-*number* are changes. Can I find Elements with part `XPath` ? 
I use `foreach()` and write data for every flight.

this is html code:

[image: HTML Code]

Comment: Why don't you get data of all the flights at once? also can you share the link from which are need to fetch data, so I can see how the elements are appearing etc...

Comment: @Rastislav: changed your question to show the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first: don't use absolute path. Even the smallest change in the html invalidate the path, especially in dynamic applications. Your `xpath` could easily be `//tr[@id='flight-932539']/td[2]`

As for your question, you can use `contains()` for partial id

```
//tr[contains(@id, 'flight-')]/td[2]
```

Comment: Just a thought, incase the element is within a frame/iframe or a svg element, I have observed in some time chrome &  firefox drivers are unable to detect elements based on logical xpaths. Though here in this case the OP havn't mentiond if the element is on Default Content or on a Frame/iFrame. Thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have one more problems,this is my code : [link](https://ibb.co/g0fgva) and I need get the text: "Axis Vega3", I don´t use class name, and content because it changes. Any solutions ?

Comment: @RastislavSrnánek The class `axis` also changing? It isn't likely. You can use `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='sponsor axis']")).GetAttribute("title");` to get the text. By the way more questions should be posted as new questions, not in the comments.

Comment: Yes it is changing.

Comment: @RastislavSrnánek You should post new question with all the details, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Ok, sorry I am new on this page. But you can help me ? I don´t know how it is work my solutions. I have similar xpath: `//div[@class='disc-vp'] `. It is original xpath, but "vp" changes. I use this :`.By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'disc-')]")` but it don´t work it.

Comment: @RastislavSrnánek You need to explain exactly what "don´t work" means. You get an exception? unexpected behavior? you also need to add the relevant html. This is to much information for the comments, that's why I suggested you post new question. New question will also allow other people to see it and help you.

Comment: @Guy this is total xpath` /html/body/div[@id='page']/div[@id='page-inner']/div[@id='main-box']/div[@class='in1']/div[@id='content-and-context']/div[@id='content']/div[@class='under-bar']/table[@class='flights']/tbody/tr[@id='flight-1029470']/td[4]/div[@class='disc-vp']` I don´t can get you site because y must be logged in. it does not write anything when I write to the label

Answer (score 0):

As Guy mentioned xpath above, for same you can easily use findElements to find all the flight details and then according perform you actions using for loop.

```
List<WebElement> WebElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@id, 'flight-')]/td[2]");

for(WebElement element : WebElements){
     //perform any operation like for click you can use
     element.getText();
}
```

> Above example is in JAVA you can do same in C# as well.

Comment: I want take the text. I need the date.

Comment: @RastislavSrnánek, for answerer it's hard to guess how does your web-site looks like and how to get required data. Update your question with appropriate `HTML` code sample or page `URL` to get better answer

Comment: Ok then you can use element.getText(), updated the code snippet as well. Please try.